# i need help making a reaction time test bot to impress my friends XD. for the website https://skoonova.com/tests/reactiontime

Tags: bots

so, I need help making on mainly because I have slow reaction time and yeah, the website https://skoonova.com/tests/reactiontime is the one I need help making the bot for if anyone would be kind enough to help, I would be appreciative.

I tried using inspect element, but I have no clue how to use it so yeah, I'm expecting like a bot that can do a reaction time of 5 MS or more.